# C++ equivalent of C# Convert

Tags: c++

In C#, there is a class with static methods for type conversions:`Convert.ToUInt16()`. Is there a C++ equivalent of these methods. I know a few, like to_string from string.h, but it would be better if all of these type conversions were in one place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> if all of these type conversions were in one place

Conversions to or from `std::string` are in `namespace std`, whilst conversions between arithmetic types are casts.

```
std::cout << std::to_string(1.2)
int i;
auto num = "1"s;
std::from_chars(num.begin(), num.end(), i);
std::cout << i;
std::cout << static_cast<std::uint16_t>(1.2);
```

For conversions of user-defined-types, rather than defining an interface like `IConvertible`, C++ allows you to define `operator int` et.al. in your class.

Answer (score 3):

Pre [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17) you can just do:

```
short int i;
std::istringstream iss{int_string};
iss >> i;
```

With [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17) you may also use [`std::from_chars`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/from_chars) - the preferred method. See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64313957/2261538).